# Moving a Document from a Library to Another Library residing in the same Subsite only Retains the Latest Version History

Tags: 2013, 2010

I am moving a document from a library to another library and I am having this issue wherein only the latest version history is being retained after moving the file to another library. The two libraries are in the same subsite.

I am viewing the history by going to "..."--->"View History".

What I am seeing is I can see the information what was changed on the latest version but the changes from previous versions is not being showed.

Example:

**No.  Modified Modified By   Size    Comments**

0.4  29/06/2015 John.Smith    100kb   Latest

```
 Document Number 123456
```

0.3  28/06/2015 John.Smith    100kb   0.3 
    *I expect to see a change here as well*

What's going on? I did the drag-and-drop thru the explorer window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root-cause of my problem. I noticed that there is a difference between a setting of a text field. I made them the same and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you open both document libraries in Explorer and drag and drop the files from one Explorer window to another, the version history will follow the document. This is different from copy-paste where you only get the latest version of the document.

Comment: I did do a drag-and-drop from explorer to another. However, the history details is not being kept. I can see the version numbers but the details on what was change isn't kept.

Comment: @AwesomeProgrammer Is versioning enabled in the destination library? Did you press shift-key before dropping the document?